# How to only kill the child process in the foreground?

Tags: c, fork, signal-handling, sigaction

I am trying to build a shell, and I've managed to code most of the functionality in, however I have a small problem.

Say I type `firefox &`. Firefox will open up as a background process. The `&` activates a BG flag that makes the parent not wait for the child process.

Then I type `gedit`. Gedit will open as a foreground process. Meaning that currently the parent is waiting for the process to close.

At this point, the parent has two processes - `firefox` and `gedit`. Firefox hasn't been waited on, and is currently in the background, whereas we are currently waiting for Gedit to finish. So far so good.

However, if I decide to send a SIGINT signal by pressing `ctrl-c`, both `firefox` and `gedit` will close. Not good, only `gedit` should be closing.

Here is my signal handler function:

```
pid_t suspended_process[10];
int last_suspended = -1;

void signal_handler(int signo){
    pid_t process = currentpid();

    // Catches interrupt signal
    if(signo == SIGINT){
        int success = kill(process, SIGINT);
    }

    // Catches suspend signal
    else if(signo == SIGTSTP){
        int success = kill(process, SIGTSTP);
        resuspended = 1;
        suspended_process[last_suspended+1] = process;
        last_suspended++;
    }
}
```

And here's the part in fork-exec code that either waits on a process, or keeps on going.

```
  else if(pid > 0){ //Parent
    current_pid = pid;

    // Waits if background flag not activated.
    if(BG == 0){
      // WUNTRACED used to stop waiting when suspended
      waitpid(current_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);

        if(WIFEXITED(status)){
          setExitcode(WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
        else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)){
          printf("Process received SIGNAL %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        }
    }
  }
```

This also happens if I suspend a process beforehand. For example, I run `firefox` and then press `ctrl-z` to suspend it. Then I run `gedit` and press `ctrl-c` to close it. Right after, if I press `fg` to restore the suspended `firefox`, it closes immediately.

I cannot find a way to only send the SIGINT signal to the foreground process, it always sends the signal to ALL children other than the parent, no matter if they are in the background, or suspended.

Just in case, this is the function that initialises the signal handler:

```
void init_handler(){
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    // If conditions for signal handling.
    // Also creates 2 signal handlers in memory for the SIGINT and SIGTSTP
    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        printf("Couldn't catch SIGINT - Interrupt Signal\n");
    if(sigaction(SIGTSTP, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        printf("Couldn't catch SIGTSTP - Suspension Signal\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather simple, but it isn't done with *signals*. Instead you must use a feature called *process groups*. Each single *job* (executable or pipeline or so) will be a separate *process group*. You can create process groups with [`setpgid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/setpgid.html) (or on some systems with `setpgrp`). You can simply set the process group of the child process after `fork` but before `exec`, and then store the process group id of this job into the job table.

Now, the process group that is in the foreground is set as the active process group for the terminal (the `/dev/tty` of the shell) with [`tcsetpgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetpgrp.html) - this is the process group that will receive <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Those process groups that belong to the same session, but not to the group set to foreground with `tcsetpgrp` will be completely oblivious to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about process groups! However, I have no idea how to incorporate `setpgid` or `tcsetpgrp` into my code. For example, I don't know how to store things into a job table, or how to use the parameters of `tcsetpgrp`. Can you please give me a short example?

Comment: Haha I've yet to try them out myself

Comment: Ah dang, I'm trying to look up how to use them, seems pretty weird

Comment: I found the way to fix the issue, all I needed to do was add a single line with `setpgid`! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Antti, I managed to find the problem. I added a single line to the fork-exec code:

```
  else if(pid > 0){ //Parent
    current_pid = pid;

    if(setpgid(pid, pid) == 0) perror("setpid");

    // Waits if background flag not activated.
    if(BG == 0){
      // WUNTRACED used to stop waiting when suspended
      waitpid(current_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);

        if(WIFEXITED(status)){
          setExitcode(WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
        else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)){
          printf("Process received SIGNAL %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        }
    }
  }
```

`if(setpgid(pid, pid) == 0) perror("setpid");`

From what I could gather, `setpgid` sets the process group ID of a process. Meaning that in the line above, ***I am setting the pgid of the process with the pid `pid` to `pid`***.

I might be wrong, I still don't fully understand the process, but the reason why this works, is that the `SIGINT` signal is only sent to the process with `pgid` `pid`. Meaning before, since I wasn't setting the `pgid` of each process, they all had the same `pgid`, hence they'd all receive the signal. However, once I set the `pgid` for each process, if I press `CTRL-C` in the middle of a foreground process, it only exits *that* running process.

At least that's from what I could gather. I still don't fully understand `tcsetpgrp`, especially what I could set as the first parameter, which is the file descriptor. Adding this line right after `setpgid`:

`tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, pid)`

Simply launches the entire program in the background whenever I `exec` a command. Instead of running `firefox` and it shows up, I run `firefox` and the whole program gets `stopped` *(according to what the terminal says at least)*. I have no idea why that happens.

Still, thanks to Antti!